# Publish web service to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, wcf

I have WCF web service for connecting to a SQL Server database on a server and to return data in JSON format.

I can run this web service on my laptop from Visual Studio 2013 correctly when I am connected to the network what server is in it, with this url :

```
 http://localhost:51220/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name=username&pass=password
```

I want to publish this web service and put it on a server (where the SQL Server database is installed). To access the web service from the internet, a url like this will be used:

```
 http://serveraddress:51220/Service1.svc/checkLogin?name=username&pass=password
```

Now, how can I publish this web service from my laptop to the server? What configurations should be set in the publish settings?

And after publish, I have 3 files: `web.config`, `service.svc` and `Sample.dll`, what can I do with them? :)

I am very amateur on make binary from WCF web service.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You should host the service in the IIS, a simple tutorial can be found here:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service